# AJAX enabled WCF Service stops working when I introduce async methods

Tags: c#, ajax, wcf, asynchronous

I've been trying to get caught up on AJAX and async web API's, however I've been having some issue getting my AJAX enabled WCF working with async methods being defined.  I followed [this MSDN example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb924552) to get AJAX enabled WCF working with synchronous methods just fine, but if I add a new method that is listed as async all the methods stop working.  Here is the example of what I have.

SampleAJAX.svc.cs

```
namespace SimpleSample
{
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class SampleAJAX
    {
        [OperationContract]
        public string GetServiceName()
        {
            return "SampleAJAX";
        }
    }
}
```

JavaScript in my Default.aspx for the example:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="SimpleOAuthSample.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Test AJAX WCF Async</title>
    <script>

        function Button1_onclick() {
            var service = SampleAJAX;
            service.GetServiceName(onSuccessPopUp, null, null);
        }

        function onSuccessPopUp(result){
            alert(result);
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div></div>
        <asp:scriptmanager runat="server">
            <Services>
                <asp:ServiceReference Path="SampleAjax.svc" />
            </Services>
        </asp:scriptmanager>
    </form>
    <p><input id="Button1" type="button" value="Call Example Service" onclick="Button1_onclick()"/></p>
</body>
</html>
```

That seems to work great, but when I add this to the SampleAJAX.cvs.cs the original GetServiceName() doesn't work anymore and neither does the new async version.  I have breakpoints in the methods and the debugger attached, but they never get hit as soon as I add the async method.

```
        [OperationContract]
        public async Task<string> GetServiceNameAsync()
        {
            await Task.Delay(2000);
            return "SampleAJAX asynchronous";
        }
```

Any ideas on what I'm missing?  I'm sure it something simple.

Comment: Are you hosting in .NET 4.5 (not 4.0)? Also, I'm not sure if WCF will do the automatic renaming for `Async` suffixes - you might have to name your WCF method `GetServiceName` instead.

Comment: I'm using .NET 4.5 specifically (not 4.5.2, even though I'm on VS 2015).  Also when I added GetServiceNameAsync() I actually added that as a new method so there was public string GetServiceName and another public async Task<string> GetServiceNameAsync.

Comment: P.S. Wow! *The* Stephen Cleary :)  I've read through a few of your articles, slides, and sample code on aysnc/await server stuff so it's awesome that you are actively engaged to help.  It was your presentations on scaling for async/await that made me want to play around with this and figure it out to make better samples for education myself.  Thanks!

Comment: Had another thought, maybe I'm going about this wrong with AJAX.  My main need is that I have JavaScript on my page, and I want to be able to call into async C# code from that.  Would you suggest a different direction like using GET endpoints instead as you do in your samples?

Comment: To be honest, when WebAPI was first released, I ported all my WCF code over that weekend and haven't looked back since. :)  If it's an endpoint for an AJAX call, IMO WebAPI is a lot easier than WCF.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, I'll see if I can just make these into WebAPIs instead and report back.

Comment: Did I underestand correctly that you have two method now: GetServiceName and GetServiceNameAsync? If you have those two then WCF service will not work. It is because WCF will take that Async postfix automatically away so you can not see it in wsdl for example.

Comment: Kari-Antti, thank you.  That was the issue, and reading back over Stephen's first comment I now understand what he was trying to say there as well.  I didn't know that WCF would modify the name of the method if I put Async on the end of it, to which it then had 2 definitions for the same method and was getting confused.  I just renamed the async method to something else with out 'Async' on the end and both methods are now working.  I'll still look into moving to WebAPI, but at least now I have an example running.  Thank you both.  Kari-Antti if you post your comment as the answer I'll mark it.